# How can i get api/stats/playback url from youtube in android without using webview?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying to use https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/playback, but the parameter values always changed and I didn’t know the reason. I wanted to know which parameters were important to use when sending a GET request to the URL given above.

I had already tried to send a GET request with the following parameters:

ns=yt ver=2 docid=QToGiWpfMHU of=OGhBO2KfadN7YJlEaDjGrg ei=b-TLZLKKHMee6dsPtuup8A0 plid=AAYCCCZmkj5llywI vm=CAEQARgEOjJBQWpSVTZsMWhqekdmQ29DRmt4dlVuNnFyWWhldElWdXE3UFlacklzY2EzR29nX1VyZ2JYQVBta0tESWlic3dkc3dWcnJmcGNkMjE3YnJMeVRpT0NkQ0FhWjh0eU1xS3dkbEVsUnRsM2dfV3AxMzhCSmtMYnNOMmJQdERDMGhVQmFGRzJGdDB6dWZ0S2gB

but nothing changed.